# Unexpected behavior when using numpy.intersect1d with an array of sets

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays containing sets. I am using numpy intersect1d to find the intersection of the two arrays but I obtain an unexpected result.

Below is a trivial example illustrating this.

```
np.intersect1d(np.array([{60}, {70}], dtype=object), np.array([{60}, {70}], dtype=object))
```

The output is array([], dtype=object), whereas I would expect np.array([{60}, {70}], dtype=object).
Is this the expected behavior in numpy? At the very least it seems counterintutive.

I see this behavior with python 3.7.3 and numpy version 1.19.2.

Comment: READ: `Return the sorted, unique values that are in both of the input arrays`.  A the source code uses `unique` and `argsort`.  It is meant to work on numbers, integers, that can be sorted and compared.

Comment: Thank you I did not realize this. I think it would also work on strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dtype=object` sets the datatype to "not-numeric" and therefore is not interpretable for calculations like the one you are trying to achieve.
Your version tries to deal with an array of string values `["{60}", "{70}"]`

I think this is what you are aiming for:

```py
>>> np.intersect1d(np.array([60, 70]), np.array([60,70]))
# output: array([60, 70])
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, this example is a bit contrived. There is no actual reason to use sets here.